# Нет исполняемых файлов php

Tags: php, linux, linux-mint

Установил php через apt:
`sudo apt install php`

Visual studio code(его расширение) запросил путь к исполняемому(executable) файлу.

В */bin* php отсутствует.

Пробовал найти через `whereis php`. Выдало:

`php: /usr/bin/php7.4 /usr/bin/php /usr/lib/php /etc/php /usr/share/php7.4-json /usr/share/php7.4-opcache /usr/share/php7.4-readline /usr/share/php7.4-common /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz`

По данным адресам файлы отсутствуют.

Где они могут быть?

Comment: `По данным адресам файлы отсутствуют.` -- как определили?

Comment: Посмотрел через проводник,  пробовал открыть  через командную строку.

Comment: а `/usr/bin/php` вас чем не устраивает?